# UIPEthernet TCp Client sends data incorrectly if reading data at the same time

Tags: node.js, tcp, arduino, ethernet

Basically, I'm trying to make a simple TCP client that can send and receive data from a Node.js server with high reliability.

This current example is connected to a simple echoserver and it works very well, until I uncomment the bottom part which is used to read the data sent back by the server, at which point the individual chars of the string start arriving seperately from each other in a random fashion.

I'm currently running the [UIPEthernet library](https://github.com/UIPEthernet/UIPEthernet) on an Arduino Nano using a [ENCJ28J60 module](https://www.m.nu/arduino-shields/ethernet-breakout-board-enc28j60).

I've done some testing, and I've so far considered the following solutions, but I don't know whether any of them will have any effect:

1: Switch to the Ethercard library

2: Try different Ethernet modules (Maybe a Nano shield)

3: Accept defeat

Here's the Arduino code:

```
#include <UIPEthernet.h>
#include <utility/logging.h>

EthernetClient client;


char data[] = "Hello server! Love, client";
int dlength = sizeof(data) / sizeof(char);

void setup() {
uint8_t mac[6] = {0x3E, 0x03, 0x44, 0x03, 0x22, 0x05};
  Ethernet.begin(mac);

}

void loop(){
if (client.connect(IPAddress(0, 0, 0, 0), 10000)) //Replace with servers IP-address
  {
while(!client){
    ; // wait until there is a client connected to proceed
  }

while (client.connected()) {
      delay(1000);

for (int o = 0; o < dlength-1; o++) {
        client.print(data[o]);
      }
client.println();
     client.flush();
      delay(100);


/*int size; //If uncommented, everything goes haywire 
      while ((size = client.available()) > 0)
      {
        uint8_t* msg = (uint8_t*)malloc(size);
        size = client.read(msg, size);
        Serial.write(msg, size);
        free(msg);
      }*/
      //Ethernet.maintain();
      /*if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        serialFlush();
        reset = true;
        break;
      }*/


}


}
}
```

And here's the Node.js code:

```
var net = require('net');


var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.write('I am an echoserver\r\n');
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("Incoming data:");
        console.log(data.toString());
        socket.write(data);
        console.log("And that is all she wrote");
   

    });
    socket.on('error', errorhandler);
});

server.listen(10000);

server.on('listening', function () {
    console.log("Server listening!");

});


server.on('error', errorhandler);






function errorhandler(err) {
    console.log("You have an error!");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Probably just an unexpected disconnect, carry on...");
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the data arrives separately?
Can you share the console log output from your node js code?

Comment: When read from the server, it will have been split into chunks like this:

Hell
o ser
ver
!